# What is utf8=✓&authenticity_token and why is it creating conflicts with mail_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, utf-8, mail-form

I am using the mail_form gem and sendgrid for my email contact form. But when I fill out the form and send the message it won't send successfully. By sending the message it should take the user to a different page where it says Thank You for your Message.

I get this utf8=✓&authenticity_token in my url and heroku logs. I think that is what is causing this problem. Can you guys please help me out?

```
2016-01-10T17:49:47.934925+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/contacts/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=mzcayVlHayBSxoka6pnUQdjz7OxaPlFICU7L%2FJlfZU4NmyiLypTSbcgaJ%2BRSLZdmhYW3NaxMrZoL0Khwr%2FiRfA%3D%3D&contact%5Bname%5D=Brandon+Espinoza&contact%5Bemail%5D=espinozabrand%40gmail.com&contact%5Bmessage%5D=Hi+how+are+you+msg+me+back+asap+pls&contact%5Bnickname%5D=&commit=Yes%21+Send+It%21" for 71.9.177.97 at 2016-01-10 17:49:47 +0000
2016-01-10T17:49:47.950056+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-01-10T17:49:47.939506+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2016-01-10T17:49:47.939670+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mzcayVlHayBSxoka6pnUQdjz7OxaPlFICU7L/JlfZU4NmyiLypTSbcgaJ+RSLZdmhYW3NaxMrZoL0Khwr/iRfA==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Brandon Espinoza", "email"=>"espinozabrand@gmail.com", "message"=>"Hi how are you msg me back asap pls", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Yes! Send It!"}
2016-01-10T17:49:47.947225+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
```

And here is my contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:error] = nil
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3 class="page-titles">Why Not Say Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
      <form style="padding: 40px 0 40px 0;">
        <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control"  %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :message %>
            <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text, class: "form-control", :cols => "30", :placeholder => "Your Message", :rows => "10" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group hidden">
            <%= f.label :nickname %>
            <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: 'leave this field blank' %>
          </div>

          <%= f.submit 'Yes! Send It!', class: " btn-default btn sendbtn" %>

        <%end%>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the user should see if the email is sent successful:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3 class="page-titles">Why Not Say Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Thank you for your message!</h1>
      <p>I'll get back to you soon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my Production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://espinozabrandblog.herokuapp.com/' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  resources :projects
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Where does `request` in `@contact.request = request` come from?

Comment: @spickermann that is from the mail_form gem. Here are the docs for that gem https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form.

Comment: @mackenzie-child could you help me out please

Comment: That's almost certainly not the problem. You could try checking @contact.errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Neither of the solutions above works to solve it.

For some reason the form tag from Bootstrap is creating the conflict. So just by taking out the `<form></form>` tag from Bootstrap lets the form submit.

#### So the form should look like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3 class="page-titles">Why Not Say Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
        <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control"  %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :message %>
            <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text, class: "form-control", :cols => "30", :placeholder => "Your Message", :rows => "10" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group hidden">
            <%= f.label :nickname %>
            <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: 'leave this field blank' %>
          </div>

          <%= f.submit 'Yes! Send It!', class: " btn-default btn sendbtn" %>

        <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should answer the first part of your question regarding the `utf8` and `authenticity_token` fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836511

[Michael Hartl explains it like this](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up):

> This code, which isn’t displayed in the browser, is used internally by Rails, so it’s not important for us to understand what it does. Briefly, it uses the Unicode character ✓ (a checkmark ✓) to force browsers to submit data using the right character encoding, and then it includes an authenticity token, which Rails uses to thwart an attack called a cross-site request forgery (CSRF).

While I haven't yet worked with this gem, could you fire up a console and test the delivery there? This should work:

```
c = Contact.new
c.email = "your@email.com"
c.name = "Your Name"
c.message = "Test Subject"
c.deliver
```

**Update:**

Your logs don't show any errors. I gather you have problems:

1. **Mail doesn't get sent.** 
   Did you receive the email when using the console? 
   If you did, then check the parameters that get passed from the form. Look at strong parameters for rails 4. Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965795

If you didn't, follow the steps in my console example again and look at `c.errors` as [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709725/what-is-utf8-authenticity-token-and-why-is-it-creating-conflicts-with-mail-for/34711614?noredirect=1#comment57169746_34709725) pointed out.

2. **User doesn't receive a 'Thank you' after submitting the form.** The easy way would be to replace `flash.now[:error] = nil` with `flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'`. If you want a dedicated page, you need that page, a redirect and the route that goes with it.

Comment: Would this mess up anything on the site? Because I only have the email form and its functionality setup for production

Comment: `Contact.new` will return a new Contact object that is not saved to the database (yet). I don't know what the `deliver` methods does, can you post the relevant code? In any case, you can use `rails console --sandbox` to roll back any changes to the database when exiting the console. If all goes well, an email would be sent out to the email specified.

Comment: MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 254.3ms

Sent mail to espinozab100@gmail.com (13.7ms)
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2016 13:53:40 -0600
From: Brandon <espinozab100@gmail.com>
To: espinozab100@gmail.com
Message-ID: <569559c47546e_4ce03ffba94141fc935c5@Bespinoza10MBP.local.mail>
Subject: Contact Form
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h4 style="text-decoration:underline">Contact Form</h4>


  <p><b>Name:</b>
  Brandon</p>

  <p><b>Email:</b>
  espinozab100@gmail.com</p>

  <p><b>Message:</b>
  TEST SUBJECT</p>

 => true

Comment: That is what happened

Comment: Please try to be more clear on what you have tried, what is happening and what your questions are. See my edit above for some pointers.

Comment: It sends in the console to my email but it won't work by just filling out the form. I added the params but it still won't do it. I've been researching over and over on how to fix this problem but can't find anything

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me. The only thing I found was this gem https://github.com/softace/utf8_enforcer_workaround. Do you think this will mess up the way people reach the site? Or its just not a good idea?